# Codemirror - find character position of overlay within a string

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I'm using codemirror 5 with custom overlay that highlights certain text (similar to search/replace demo).

How can I find the start and end character position of the custom overlay within a line, when iterating though all the strings with `cm.eachLine()`?

Ultimately, I want to set a gutter marker, and attach a click event that will modify the highlighted text. This sounds relatively straightforward, however I cannot find an easy way to find the character position of overlay within a string.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle / codepen of what you have tried so far?

Comment: so far I have tried to iterate through styles property of each line `cm.eachLine(function(ln){ $.each(ln.styles, function(indx, style){ .. });` but styles are in some weird format, which is some kind of array of positions and overlays. Is there any helper function to get overlay for each line in more usable format?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this doesn't use the `editor.eachLine()` feature, but it works.

First, find each of your custom spans. Loop through each span finding the linenumber and then an array of characters that will help us find the character positions as `lineView`. Go ahead and define your `start` and `end` values as `0`. Now loop through each `lineView` item, if start and end are 0, this item is an object, this item's parent node exists, and this span is equal to this item's parent node, set the start and end variables. The start variable is found two items behind the text object.

```
var spans = $("span.cm-custom-overlay", editor.display.lineDiv);
$.each(spans, function () {
    var span = $(this);
    var lineNumber = span.closest(".CodeMirror-line").closest("div[style]").index();
    var lineView = editor.display.renderedView[lineNumber].measure.map;
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;

    for (var i in lineView) {
        if (
            !start &&
            !end &&
            typeof lineView[i] == "object" &&
            lineView[i].parentNode &&
            span[0] == lineView[i].parentNode
        ) {
            start = lineView[i - 2];
            end = lineView[i - 1];
        }
    }

    console.log("start: ", start, " end: ", end);
});
```

Comment: I think this is pretty much the same as looping through `$.each(ln.styles)` and getting start/end position from there.

Comment: @user2531657 yeh, but this way has more checks to pass.